# How to call %random% same as previous %random% in CMD?

Tags: windows, variables, random, cmd

How to call the same random number in cmd multiple times?
Can I set it as variable and then call it or can I define it as !random!  ?

Comment: Are you wanting to use the same RANDOM number for all of the cmd script, or are you wanting a new RANDOM number each time?

Comment: My program is making siple text file that ends with random number, and I want to print the name of that file which I cant if I don't know the random number

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this and it works:

```
set MYRANDOM=%random%
```

Now, you can "call" or reference your stored random number.  eg...

```
echo %MYRANDOM%
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable for the random file name. Then, use that throughout the script.

```
SET "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\my_app_%RANDOM%.tmp"
IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" (DEL "%TEMPFILE%")

ECHO>>"%TEMPFILE%" Reached line 22
aprog.exe >>"%TEMPFILE%"

ECHO The temporary file is "%TEMPFILE%"
```